# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. after adding extenal library

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing an android app. In that am using in external library `spoon-runner-1.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` after adding this when i try to execute the application results `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

my gradle file is shown below

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "venki.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental = true;

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/spoon-runner-1.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

**1.** I have tried cleaning project and rebuild project.
**2.** and also Invalidate cache and restart android studio.
**3.** Increasing heapsize.
**4.**android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

Nothing helps for me. Please help me out from this.

Comment: remove line compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') and try it

Comment: result is same even after removing that line

Answer (score -1):

This must be due to some RAM issues. Please close android studio and kill java processes and try to run application again.

Comment: it doesn't helped me